# Access denied for user when trying to run a custom command on a shared hosting server

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

**SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'testuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: delete from `pending_reservations` where `1` is null)**
This is the error that i get when i try to run the following command in laravel

```php
public function handle()
    {
        $current_date_time = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMinutes(15)->toDateTimeString();

        PendingReservation::where('created_at' >= $current_date_time)->delete();
    }
```

I have access to terminal in my cPanel, but I can only login as the 'testuser' which again, doesn't have any access.

Comment: Can you make sure that `PendingReservation` model does not have a custom database connection configuration?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know any details about that error, but I can say that your code has 2 problems.

First, `where(...)` returns a query you to perform another one. So it doesn't return the data. You have to request it by using get().

Second, delete() method works with a single instance of a model, not collections. So what you need to do is to get an instance and delete it. But in your case, you will have a collection of instances. So you need a loop.

```php
$reservations = PendingReservation::where('created_at' >= $current_date_time)->get();

foreach ($reservations as $reservation) {
    $reservation->delete();
}
```

Comment: This is not true, if `PendingReservation` is a model it can make the query as it is. 
[See the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#deleting-models-using-queries) for more information.

Comment: Of course PendingReservation is a model. But whenever you get more than one instance of a model, you have a collection. And delete method works with a single instance. You can't give it a collection and expect it works. So what part is not true?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you still need to read the documentation I sent you in my previous comment. You can't be so sure that you can't do something if you don't know the Framework.